# Image conversion to Grayscale using ImageMagick is very dark

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, grayscale, brightness, monochrome

I converted a bunch of "normal" JPG photos via

```
convert infile -colorspace Gray outfile
```

to monochrome. However the result is for all images very dark. Here a sample conversion: [original photo](http://www.halloleo.net/etc/external/im-mono-issue/Clouds%20over%20Hunter%20Park_pano_edited.jpg) and [converted monochrome image](http://www.halloleo.net/etc/external/im-mono-issue/Clouds%20over%20Hunter%20Park_pano_edited_mono.jpg).

Is there a better way to convert a photo-realistic image with ImageMagick to gray-scale?

Comment: Sounds about right. Do you have examples?

Comment: Yep, just added a sample conversion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colorspace) states that when changing the color space, the colors are converted from their original gamma to linear before the conversion. You need to convert them back to an appropriate gamma.

```
convert infile -colorspace Gray -gamma 2.2 outfile
```

Comment: Great idea. Is there an easy way to find out the gamma _a jpg was "recorded" with_?

Comment: @halloleo, standard images are always 2.2 unless they were generated on an old Mac.

Comment: I just found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082396/iphone-grayscaled-image-is-too-dark-can-i-change-the-opacity-of-gray-scale-im?rq=1) for a similar question. It says to convert the RGB values via the formula:

    Y = 0.30 x Red + 0.59 x Green + 0.11 x Blue

This looks to me like a very different approach. Do I have to do both??? I'll try it out.